# Firebase realtime database public rule

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What if I publish my android app using firebase realtime database in public mode,because I don't need any authentication.It says

**Public access makes your database open to anyone, even people not using your app, so be sure to restrict your database again when you set up authentication.**

I don't clearly understand how can anyone have access to my database if their app's are not connected to my database and they also doesn't have login passowrd for the firebase account.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A URL is associated with your database.  The URL is shown at the top of the Database tab of the Firebase Console. For example:

```
https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com/
```

If the security rules for the database allow public access, anyone who knows the URL can read and write to the database using the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/).

Comment: Thank you for response,so it figures out if nobody has my login and password for firebase account,it's safe right?

Comment: Like Bob said, it depends on what security rules you set up. If you have something like {
  "rules": {
    "mydata": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}, then anyone with the URL can read/write to your DB. They would not need your admin credentials.

Comment: Although it may seem unlikely that anyone will be able to guess or discover your Project ID, and thus know your database URL, it's really not safe to leave your security rules public.

Comment: The Project ID is in the `google-services.json` used in your build and, I would guess, is stored somewhere in your app's APK in a form that might be accessible to a hacker.

Comment: @BobSnyder Which means reverse engineering will provide the credential of the app?

Comment: Last part of URL it not fixed to ```firebase.io``` but depends on the location of the project -> [rtdb-locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations)